# How do I turn off a program with a java code?

Tags: java, browser

Hi guys I open in my java application I open a browser page with this code:

```
String URL = "https://www.google.com/";
try {
    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URL));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I have to turn off the browser,  Is there a code to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no Java API to close the browser.

Comment: Ok, there is a method to reload the page?

Comment: @user3850946, no, there is not. Note that there is very limited OS specific features available in the Java API since they try to provide a public API that is platform independent. Opening an URL with the OS' default application through the `Desktop` class is pretty much all you get. Closing the browsers, or refreshing the browser (any interaction really) is not possible with plain Java.

Answer (score 0):

There sort-of is but it's not very reliable. But if you have to, you can try with keyboard shortcuts and mouse clicks using Java Robot API.

```
    public class RobotTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String URL = "https://www.google.com/";
            try {
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URL));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Robot javaRobot;
            try {
                javaRobot = new Robot();
                javaRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                javaRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
                javaRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                javaRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```